# Runtime errors at Celestlab

Tags: scilab

Very frequent error in Celestlab for  Scilab are:

Undefined variable: CL_cw_hohmannLine
Undefined variable: %CL_deg2rad

etc.

Bestregarsd Piotr

How to fix this and simillar bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper location to report such a bug (and get help from maintainers):
https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/celestlab/#leave_a_comment

By the way,

- you should provide a minimal copy/pastable example able to reproduce these errors.
- you should indicate which Scilab's version you use